# Packing DLLs with setuptools (where to put them?)

Tags: python, dll, ctypes, setuptools

I have a module that uses a DLL that I made. This DLL depends on another DLL provided by a third party. When I load my library (with ctypes), the operation crashes unless it finds the 2nd DLL. After a lot of searching, I solved this by adding the location of the libraries to the PATH.

Now I'm packing my module and the DDLs to give to other people using setuptools. How should I deal with this DLL dependency situation? Should I detect and add the installation folder to the PATH of the user in setup.py? Should I move the libraries to a specific folder already in the PATH? Is there a common practice?

**Just some notes**: I own and can distribute both DLLs, I can make changes in both of them but I cannot merge them (one is in Fortran and the other in C). These are libraries not likely to exist on the user's pc. For now I work on Windows, but the idea is to provide also the .so libraries, thus an answer covering both (Windows and Linux) would be appreciated.